# Java string comparision logic issue?

Tags: java, string, apache-poi

```
for(int counter=0;counter<cells.size();counter++){
            System.out.println("The name typed is "+name);
            System.out.println("got to the loop");
            String storedName=cells.get(counter).toString();
            System.out.println("The cell name is "+storedName);


            if(storedName==name){
                System.out.println("Found it!");
                break;
            }else{

                System.out.println("Did not find it");
            }

        }
```

**OUTPUT:**

**The name typed is JACK**

**got to the loop**

**The cell name is JACK**

**Did not find it**

I don't understand why the if statement never returns true?

Comment: `String` comparison in Java is done with `String#equals` method not `==`.  `equals` will compare the content where as `==` will compare the memory reference of the two `String`s

Comment: Brain lapse, thank you very much.